# Distinguish Output while using UNION in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am using UNION to get joined output from 2 rows. A and B, following is the code.

```
"SELECT `ent_id` as `id`, `owner_id`, `category_id`, `ent_name` as `name`, `ent_details` as `details` FROM `A` WHERE  `category_id` = '$cat' 

UNION

SELECT `service_id` as `id`, `owner_id`, `category_id`, `service_name` as `name`, `service_details` as `details` FROM `B` WHERE `category_id` = '$cat'
```

The query works absolutely fine however I now want to know which output is from table A and which from B.

Is there a way to do this? If so how?

Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a constant value to each select:

```
select 'table a' as source_table, ... from A where ...
union all
select 'table b' as source_table, ... from B where ...
```

Also, `union` eliminates duplicates between the two sets that form the union which `union all` doesn't. If there can be no duplicates you should use `union all` for better performance.